# Why no linear scaling of Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, scaling

I am trying to build one horizontal scalability system based on Redis Cluster. So I've measured the throughput of Redis Cluster with different nodes. But finally, the measured result doesn't show the linear scalability as the [cluster spec](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) stated, “High performance and linear scalability up to 1000 nodes.”

redis cluster benchmark:
[image: redis cluster benchmark]

The image above shows the measure result of redis cluster of (3+3), (4+4), (5+5), (6+6), (8+8), (10+10) and (12+12). (3+3) means 3 master node plus 3 slave nodes. The result of C (reate) and you (update) don't show the linear scalability of redis cluster as following picture.

I'd like to know why these measured result don't show the linear scalability. Is there any possible reason to limit the scaling?

My test environment and related information are described as below

#### Server

- HW: HP BL460c G9, 24 CPU (E5-2620 v3 @2.40GHz), 64G memory, 300G disk

I have two machines. In order to know the capacity of one HW machine, I run all master nodes on one machine and all slaves nodes on another machine. All redis nodes will be include in one Redis Cluster.

- OS: SLES 12

I have updates some system settings to achieve higher performance.

```
echo 65535 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn
echo 65535 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
sysctl vm.swappiness=0
```

Furthermore, I've turned off the swap, which could cause very unstable throughput when AOF re-write happened even swappiness is already set to 0. As observed, 15 million records in my test will occupy around 48G memory.

- Redis 3.0.6: To eliminate the burst caused by RDB, I turned off all RDB and only enable AOF. For other configurations in redis.conf, just left with default values.

#### Client

- HW: HP DL380 G7, 16 CPU (E5620 @2.40GHz), 24G memory, 600G disk
- OS: SLES 12
- YCSB (0.6.0) with jedis (2.8.0)

I will use hash key to store all records (1 key and 21 fields) and N sorted sets to store all keys and its random scores. Here N is the number of master nodes in the cluster. N sorted sets will be distributed evenly in each master node.
The YCSB workload configuration is pasted below:
workload=com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload

```
recordcount=15000000
operationcount=150000000
insertstart=0
fieldcount=21
fieldlength=188
readallfields=true
writeallfields=false
fieldlengthdistribution=zipfian
readproportion=0.0
updateproportion=1.0
insertproportion=0
readmodifywriteproportion=0.0
scanproportion=0
maxscanlength=1000
scanlengthdistribution=uniform
insertorder=hashed
requestdistribution=zipfian
hotspotdatafraction=0.2
hotspotopnfraction=0.8
table=subscriber
measurementtype=histogram
histogram.buckets=1000
timeseries.granularity=1000
```

At most cases, the computer resource is enough in my view though the throughput already hit the limit.

- CPU: there are much CPU left, 60~70% CPU idle
- I/O usage: it's not so busy, it's 30~40% utility at peak time.
- Memory: only memory could be exhausted almost at peak time, i.e. when AOF re-write happened. At most time it's around 80%.